# jquery css not applying dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a overlay div look like below with id & class,

```
<div id="findBudget" class="openedlist bottom-side open" style="height: auto; width: 1080px; top: 80px;">
```

And it is perfectly showing overlay with open.

After browser click back from next page to this div page, while the page loads, the style of the id 'findBudget', need to change dynamically like below,

```
 style="height: auto; width: ''; top: 80px;"
```

I tried with below jquery script in browser back function.

```
 if ($('#findBudget').hasClass('open')) {
    $('#findBudget').css('width','');
  }
```

But still it is showing like this (old),

```
  <div id="findBudget" class="openedlist bottom-side open" style="height: auto; width: 1080px; top: 80px;">
```

Please show me where I am doing mistake, before switch on coffee machine.
Thanks

Comment: Where are you running the javascript/css code at?

Comment: it works... http://jsfiddle.net/6JSYU/

Comment: @LGVentura, shouldn't it be http://jsfiddle.net/ericwu91/6JSYU/1/ ?

Comment: Check if the code fires at all. Add console.log('test') and check it in your dev tools

Comment: @EricWu read again "the style of the id 'findBudget', need to change dynamically like below" it says width auto, not width 0px.

Comment: @LGVentura, ...no. What needs to be changed is the width, not the height.From `height: auto; width: 1080px; top: 80px;` to `height: auto; width: ''; top: 80px;`. From 1080px to ''.

Comment: @EricWu i guess width:'' means width auto, not width 0px, since if you dont specify your width it will be set auto.

Comment: @LGVentura, if your statement is correct, then the div you presented in your fiddle should have a computed width of 20px, since though it has a 20px-padding, it has no content at all. Which is not the case.
... I could be wrong in this. If so, kindly correct me.

Comment: @EricWu the padding and background-color are just to exemplify and allow it to inspect the result in the browser inspector. The CSS is not in question. With this update you sent on my fiddle would also have the same problem, right? but it does not matter. The example was made for him to see that the width was changed to '' (auto) with js he wrote.

Comment: @LGVentura Hmmm, that explains it. Well, thanks for the enlightment. Sorry for looking like a troll :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the code you have in your answer works just fine. I am guessing that either (1) it doesn't do what you want or (2) it doesn't work because of code that you haven't pasted into your answer (events not getting wired or things of that nature).That said, if you are just trying to hide the element you can call:

```
$('#findBudget').css('display','none');
```

**See The Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/fd379/1/

---

**EDIT**: One more note - if you want the div to size exactly to the same size as the text you can use `float: left`. You can see this working in the following update to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fd379/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to erase the width instruction.

If that's all, you can set it with a zero px to ensure that it will arrive as zero.

```
if ($('#findBudget').hasClass('open')) {
$('#findBudget').css('width','0px');
}
```

If you want it to disappear, simply use

```
if ($('#findBudget').hasClass('open')) {
$('#findBudget').hide();
}
```